# How pages works in Git on different branchs?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in my repository(SAMPLE)

1. master .. under Master ---> AA (folder)--> A.html
2. gh-pages.. under gh-pages ---> BB (folder) --> B.html

I have make master as my default.

If my user name is USER ,then i got `USER.github.com/SAMPLE/BB/B.html` -- it works fine and I can see my page live.

So how can i view the master pages. like `(USER.github.com/SAMPLE/AA/A.html)`

Comment: But pages under branch "gh-pages" are accessible and i can see this in live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gh-pages` branch is special, and the only branch that is mapped to your `USER.github.com/SAMPLE` web space.  If you want other files to appear in your `gh-pages` branch, you'll need to explain more about what you're trying to do for other people to be able to make good suggestions about how to do that.  For example:

- are these generated files that you're publishing there, like automatically generated documentation?
- is your master branch just the pages that you want to display anyway?

etc. etc.

Comment: k.. i just want to display few HTML pages which have some images and javascript , is one branch enough ? if i have only master then how can i run that files in a specific folder in master branch ?

Comment: Yes, if you just want to serve some files from `http://USER.github.com/SAMPLE` you can just work on the `gh-pages` branch - there's no need for the `master` branch.  If you want to bring in all the files you have from `master`,  you can merge that branch into `gh-pages` as @Lakshaman Prasad suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the `master` branch into the `gh-pages` branch.

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git commit -m 'Added AA folder from the master to be available via the web-page'
git push origin gh-pages
```